# How to 'simulate' an input device?

Tags: amplifier, noise, preamp, guitar-pedal

I made a diy guitar amplifier with two seperate amplifiers. When potentiometer is raised something strange and annoying begins - various whispers, noises and reacts really strange.  HOWEVER this never happens when any input device is connected.  I don't intend to search for the problem in the schematic as it is really quite messy between the cables and if something would go wrong I would be in trouble to find it.  So - how to 'simulate' a device input?  Of course the main input connection must function as it is.  Any suggestions will be helpful :)

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you're trying to do. What do you expect to simulate that can solve your humming problem?

Comment: I think this an XY problem. Instead of trying to "simulate" a device input, you might want to identify the root cause of the trouble and fix _that_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two fairly easy choices. (1) replace your input jack (I assume 1/4" phono jack with one with an extra contact that closes when nothing is inserted (see photo [here (Wikipedia image)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Jack-plug--socket-switch.jpg)and connect it so that the input is shorted when no jack is inserted, or (2) buy an extra jack and internally short the contacts; insert this into your input when nothing else is connected.